# Cannot connect to Aurora RDS using workbench over ssh

Tags: mysql-workbench, aws, aurora

I set up an environment on AWS that consists of a VPC with a private and public subnet following the instructions for Magento Quick Start: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/magento/architecture.html

The private subnet includes:

- an EC2 instance (web server)
- an Aurora RDS that connects to the web server

The public subnet includes:

- a bastion instance for ssh connections to the EC2 instance in the private subnet

Generally, I can connect to Aurora RDS via ssh by connecting to the bastion host, then connecting to the private EC2 instance, and then to the RDS, however this makes it hard to perform simple tasks on the RDS.

Is it possible to connect to the RDS using mySQL workbench over ssh through the bastion?

I've tried everything but nothing seems to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This took me forever....

Other than the permissions in the security groups that i set initially, i had to allow port forward on the bastion instance.

1. connect to the bastion instance via SSH
2. go to /etc/ssh
3. sudo nano sshd_config
4. Set: AllowPortForwarding yes
5. restart the instance
6. Connect with workbench